# Problem trying to install pyPENELOPE

Tags: 18.04

I'm not an expert in Ubuntu, so maybe it's a stupid question, but I'm having problems trying to install a software called pyPENELOPE.
Following the steps in their site http://pypenelope.sourceforge.net/download.html I tried the comand

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/python-penelope_0.2.10-1_all.deb
```

But I've received the error message

```
Preparing to unpack .../python-penelope_0.2.10-1_all.deb ...
Upgrading pyPENELOPE
Unpacking python-penelope (0.2.10-1) over (0.2.10-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-penelope:
 python-penelope depends on python-wxgtk2.8; however:
  Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python-penelope (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-penelope
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Install the dependency:  `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8` before unpacking pyPenelope.

Comment: I've received the message 
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-wxgtk2.8' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Comment: I am also trying to get pyPenelope to work (by converting the code to python 3). Tanus, did you manage to get it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `sudo dpkg --install filename.deb` only *identifies* dependencies. It doesn't handle those dependencies automatically. You must install the dependencies (in the correct order) yourself.

That's why your output is complaining about "dependency problems": dpkg is telling you that you neglected to install the other package *first*.

- Try using `sudo apt install ./filename.deb` instead. Apt DOES handle dependencies automatically.
- If you read that `dpkg -i` instruction somewhere, please ping the author to update their documentation.

However, that won't work either for you due to a SEPARATE coincidental problem: The package `python-wxgtk2.8` was dropped from Ubuntu after Ubuntu 14.04.

- Download the older package from http://packages.ubuntu.com and install it. It might work...or it might not.

Seems like you're trying to use very old, unmaintained software. If you encounter problems, we don't provide support for it (sorry).

Comment: holy moly, that worked FINE. Thank you!